# Correct usage of phrase "about + to"

Tags: infinitives

I'd like to know whether the usage of *'about to'* is correct in these sentences:

> I'm about to hate you.

and

> I'm about to start hating you.

Are either, or both, of these examples wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct constructions and perfectly viable, although "about to" is generally relegated to spoken English.  That said, I would argue that the transition period from "not hating" to "hating" is an un-announcable event; I would not know when or if I would start hating anyone.  However, these exact phrases are often used in friendly banter.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically correct and they both use idiomatic English. They would most likely be use in conversation as a semi-humorous rebuff or criticism.

The implication is, "I don't hate you right now but, if you continue with your current attitude/behaviour I probably will hate you very soon."